# How to make win prob. XGBoost model sum to 100%?

Tags: r, xgboost, modeling, theory, tidymodels

So I am building a football win probability model using `tidymodels` and XGBoost in R. It is using box score averages (yards, pts., etc.) by each team *entering* that game -- to mimic what would be available on game day.

My larger data frame looks something like this (abbreviated version; actual df has more data points):

```
  team  game_id   pts def_pts opp_pts opp_def_pts did_win
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>   <fct>
1 PAT         1  24.3    19.8    17.4        21.4       1
2 DAL         1  17.4    21.4    24.3        19.8       0
```

Where the model takes into account both that teams' averages *and* their opponents' averages (offense and defense).

When running the model, however, **XGBoost appears to not understand that each team is playing one another**, resulting in projected win percentages that **do not add up to 100%**. For example, one team might be given a 75% chance to win but their opponent a 15% chance to win -- this error results in total win percentages both over and under 100%.

```
  .pred_0 .pred_1
    <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.250   0.750
2   0.850   0.150
```

My new thought is to, instead, run the model with just one team -- since the data is essentially being mirrored, anyways (team + opponent data is shown for each observation). Then, I would take the difference between the resulting win percentage and 1 to estimate the opposition's chances of winning.

But is this good modeling practices, or is there a better way to 'tell' XGBoost that two teams are playing one another and, such, each "group" of game ids should have predictions that add up to 100%? Would using just one team per game give inaccurate measurements as to the projected win percentage of the other team?

Comment: Note: The rows add up to 1. Coincidence?

Comment: That is to be expected, no? The classification model will spew out probabilities of winning or losing for either team in this scenario, and they must add up to 1 (0.25 + 0.75 and 0.85 + 0.15). The problem is that the columns do not add up to 1, and this is for a single game. There cannot be an 85% chance that one team loses and a 25% chance that the other team loses (110%). Shouldn't this, also, logically add up to 1? @MartinGal